# Creating custom array class in Ruby and struggling with a basic piece of functionality

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a class that creates arrays.  (Yes, I realize that's already available in ruby.  This is more of an exercise.)  The class, SpecialArray, creates an array based on input that's either given by the user when creating a new array or added to the array later. I'm having trouble connecting these two pieces of functionality. Creating an array works fine, but adding to it does not. I had thought that the output atrr_reader would hold the exiting array in memory, but now I'm not sure.  Any idea how I can make this work?

```
    class SpecialArray
      attr_reader :input, :output

      def initialize(*input)
        @input = input.flatten
        @output = []
        generate_array
      end

      def generate_array
        input.each do |e|
          add(e)
        end
        output
      end

            #update start
    def numerical(element)
      element.class == Fixnum
    end

    def unique(element)
      output.include? element ? false : true
    end

    def valid_e(element)
      unique(element) && numerical(element)
    end

    def numerical(elment)
      element.class == Fixnum
    end

    def unique(element)
      output.include? element ? false : true
    end

    def valid_e(element)
      unique(element) && numerical(element)
    end
        #update end

      def add(element)
        unless valid_e(element) == false
          output.push(element)
        end
        output
      end

    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work fine to me, both `@input` and `@output` contain the array I passed in:

```
irb(main):032:0> a = SpecialArray.new(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
irb(main):034:0> puts a.inspect
#<SpecialArray:0x296e7e8 @input=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
                         @output=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]>
=> nil
```

**EDIT Full Code**

```
irb(main):001:0> class SpecialArray
irb(main):002:1>       attr_reader :input, :output
irb(main):003:1>
irb(main):004:1*       def initialize(*input)
irb(main):005:2>         @input = input.flatten
irb(main):006:2>         @output = []
irb(main):007:2>         generate_array
irb(main):008:2>       end
irb(main):009:1>
irb(main):010:1*       def generate_array
irb(main):011:2>         input.each do |e|
irb(main):012:3*           add(e)
irb(main):013:3>         end
irb(main):014:2>         output
irb(main):015:2>       end
irb(main):016:1>
irb(main):017:1*         #...
irb(main):018:1*
irb(main):019:1*       def add(element)
irb(main):020:2>         unless valid_e(element) == false
irb(main):021:3>           output.push(element)
irb(main):022:3>         end
irb(main):023:2>         output
irb(main):024:2>       end
irb(main):025:1>
irb(main):026:1*       def valid_e(e)
irb(main):027:2>         return true;
irb(main):028:2*       end
irb(main):029:1>
irb(main):030:1*         #...
irb(main):031:1*     end
=> nil
irb(main):032:0> a = SpecialArray.new(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
irb(main):034:0> puts a.inspect
#<SpecialArray:0x296e7e8 @input=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
                         @output=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]>
=> nil
```

Comment: I was unclear in my question above.  What I'm struggling with is how to leverage the "add" method that I wrote. I end up with @output = [].

Comment: I am still confusing as to what you are having trouble with, I pasted your code directly into irb and I received the output you desire. I suspect that the problem lies in your `valid_e(x)` method since I added that one myself. Can you post that above ?

Comment: I just popped the code that you wrote into an irb session and I came up with output=[].  Did you modify the original code I wrote in some way?  I'm confused as to how your code populated the @output array if it's the same as mine.

Comment: I will post the entire piece of code I used, I had to implement the `valid_e(x)` method since you didn't show it above. I set mine to always return `true`, I suspect that yours is always returning `false`.

Comment: You were right!  If I take out the unless, everything loads up fine.  I think the problem might be in my "unique" method above.  But I'll have to investigate further.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: So the problem is in your `unique(element)` method, you need to have parentheses around the conditional part of the ternary operator. change `output.include? element ? false : true` to `(output.include? element) ? false : true' Keep in mind that this type of debugging is something you should be able to do. All I did was add print statement to your methods.